# GooglePay API payment token is not getting decrypted

Tags: javascript, google-pay

We are trying  to integrate Google Pay on the web in my project so that we can make payments through Googlepay. Firstdata is our payment processor.We are generating the payment token as mentioned in [this link](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/tutorial).

We are providing the gateway and gatewayMerchantId in our code as below(I have intentionally masked the gatewayMerchantId in this code snippet as i dont want to publicize it). The gatewayMerchatId is what the payment processor provided us.

```js
     const tokenizationSpecification = {
        type: 'PAYMENT_GATEWAY',
        parameters: {
           'gateway':'firstdata',
           'gatewayMerchantId': '***********'

        }
      };
```

We are setting the Google provided merchant id to 'Example Merchant'(see below) as we are in TEST environment and we can use any value for Google provided merchant id in TEST environment.

```js
    function getGooglePaymentDataRequest() {
        const paymentDataRequest = Object.assign({}, baseRequest);
        paymentDataRequest.allowedPaymentMethods = [cardPaymentMethod];
        paymentDataRequest.transactionInfo = getGoogleTransactionInfo();
        paymentDataRequest.merchantInfo = {
          // @todo a merchant ID is available for a production environment after approval by Google
          // See {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/test-and-deploy/integration-checklist|Integration checklist}
          // merchantId: '0123456789',
          merchantName: 'Example Merchant'
        };
        return paymentDataRequest;
      }
```

After we generate the encrypted payment token using Google API  we invoke the First Data api using the encrypted Token  to process the payment. But FirstData is not able to decrypt the token. I am wondering if we are missing any steps for Google Pay payments in our side in TEST environment.  We are not doing any configuration steps in our side other than setting the gatewayMerchantId provided by our payment processor in our code.

Any guidance or pointers will be very helpful.

Comment: there is a sample code repository https://github.com/googletez/web-payment-samples/tree/master/demo you should check & hope it will give you some visibility

Comment: What is the error that you are getting back from FirstData? Have you tried looking at their [documentation](https://github.com/payeezy/google_pay/blob/master/guide/FirstDataGooglePayIntegrationGuide201802.pdf) from their [github repository](https://github.com/payeezy/google_pay)? The samples are for Android, it should hopefully be enough to point you in the right direction.